# How to make a homepage using index.php inside folder

Tags: php, deployment

I've got a domain name and web hosting. I'm trying to make my PHP build website online. I have uploaded all files in a folder.

When users visit this:

```
www.example.com/
```

I want them to be redirected to this:

```
www.example.com/Folder/
```

What should I do?

Comment: Move all the files in `/` into `/Folder`? As long as you've not hardwired your site URLs to the root folder, it should be fine.

Comment: You can make changes in .htaccess files to do this

Comment: @halfer It's obvious what you are saying. I want that if someone type `www.example.com` and press enter then he/she should be redirected to `www.example.com/Folder`
@cartina I'm using shared web hosting from 'godaddy'. Is it still possible to make changes to .htaccess at www.godaddy.com

Comment: @Harish, I accurately answered the question you asked. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should write in your .htaccess file smth like that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/folder/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or in www.example.com/index.php do:

```
header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header ("Location: http://www.example.com/folder/");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can move it to a seprate folder

```
root/yourfolder/index.php
```

now the url will be

```
mysite.com/yourfolder
```

or you can do it with

```
.htaccess
```

Comment: how to make changes in .htaccess in shared hosting with godaddy